API Security and protection from non trusted clients
We are facing an issue with a malicious user who has details about how our website works. Using the developer tools in the browser, the login and subsequent APIs are studied and a mobile app is built which internally hits our APIs.
Genuine users use this mobile app, since it acts as an aggregator platform accepting user request and transforming them and hitting the genuine back end applications.
This is a risk as this mobile app has access to our data.
We have implemented certain controls in our web page to identify whether the API request is genuinely originating from our button clicks (hidden values and random numbers generated from client which will be validated by server) - but then its not fully effective.
All the client side code is visible ( even though its obfuscated ) and hence this can be mimicked by any other client interface ( Web UI / mobile app )
I believed this is a common problem and would have been addressed by applying specific controls/patterns, especially in banking/finance domain.
Kindly revert with your views to effectively address this concern
We have few controls in place to address this problem - but would like to know industry best practices around this concern, which might be already adopted by financial institutions ( Setting origin header / CORS etc. )
Summary of problem :
A malicious developer can understand all your application APIs including login (from the browser developer tools) and then he can build a new application( basically another custom client), by invoking your APIs directly from his UI.
Users accessing the malicious application will see a different UI for login and subsequent actions - but the malicious app is just a pass through application, which will route all API calls to original back end application

Probably thus question will get auto deleted without much views....if the quesiton is absurd then nobody answers to it - this whole point of auto delete is actually reducing the effectiveness of this platform

i don't think it is a bot problem - I think it is a not reading how to ask problem. Where is the code? What have you tried? You haven't even clearly defined a question (no question mark in the whole text)

Problem is basically anybody can build a UI for the backend services - if the APIs , input , output and headers are known.  Is there a way this can be arrested?  What is done now is to check headers,  nounce which will be sent from client to server etc. But this is not effective, what ever happens in the html/JavaScript client code can be replayed by a hacker

your question (or actually lack of a question) is too broad and is correct to be downvoted - this can't be addressed by SO. You should research some books/articles on API Security and then ask a question about a specific use case / problem you are having

@lives Adressing your first comment: There is a broad community, it is very likely that someone was online at this time. Addressing your second comment: You could read the rules for auto-deletion in the help center or on meta. Three downvotes is not enough to delete your question. Also your question has to be closed first (with some exceptions), therefore 3 users have to vote to close.

@lives I don't understand your problem. You tagged your question with [spring-security], so I would think, you etablished some kind of authentication. A login form, for example. So no one could access your API. If the user has an account, so you could identify him/her and ban him/her.

I believed this is a common problem and would have been addressed by applying specific controls/patterns, especially in banking/finance domain. You can't access a banking API without authentication, in the EU you also need 2FA.

Apologies - looks like I could not explain the problem right. If I am a hacker and I can understand all your application APIs including login ( from the developer tools) , then I can build a new application by invoking those APIS with the right headers and payload. Users accessing my application will see a different page for login - but eventually my application is just a pass through application which will route all API calls to another application

The short answer: You cannot work against this by trying to control the client.
The long one:
When creating an API that gives a user access to your data, the user will be able to call that API and its endpoints to access that data. This is by design and what you want, otherwise you would not give them access to your API (and that data) in the first place.
What you want to do is stop the user from accessing your API using anything that isn't your application. As you've correctly identified, giving a user access to your application allows them to reverse engineer it and find out how to call your endpoints.
What you've tried so far boils down to:

Generate some data (presumably some hash) in the client to send along with a request to verify it
Obfuscate your frontend code to make reverse-engineering harder
Setting a restrictive CORS header

From these three methods, the first two basically boil down to "You want to make it harder for someone to reverse-engineer your application". This is what the security field refers to as "Security through obscurity" (also see CWE-656). It is generally not seen to make your application more secure, at most it will gain you some time until your application can successfully be reverse-engineered.
CORS functionality, the third point, is the only one that has provable merit here, though as you noted it is also not a magical solution to all your problems. What a well-designed CORS policy would do for you is prevent another website to send a request to yours to perform an action the user may be unaware of. It does however not stop me from creating an application that intentionally sets the Origin header to be the same as yours, bypassing that protection.
Now that we've established why all three of your attempted methods do not work for what you're trying to do, let's look into what you can do and what you should do:
In summary, you are barking up the wrong tree. You are trying to have your client be the only way to interact with your API to protect data (?) while it is not possible to trust the client sending information. What you should do is fix security problems where you can control and fix them (server-side) instead of trying (and inevitably failing) to control the client.
What you should be doing instead is to take a step back and look at what you're ultimately trying to achieve and then define what you should do depending on it:
Are you trying to protect...

Confidentiality? Add authentication and proper authorization to your application to prevent users from gaining access to data they shouldn't be able to access in the first place. This boils down to "Does user X with their permissions need to be able to access Y? If not, require certain permissions to access Y that X does not have."
Integrity? Make sure your users use the correct application downloaded from the correct source (e.g. provide checksums to allow them to verify it by themselves). This is the hardest part and what cannot really be done automatically with the threat model you're defining (as in, there is no singular best option to do this).
Availability? Add sensible rate-limits and other checks to prevent someone from clogging up your server with requests to take it down.

As you've mentioned financial institutions, they have not solved this problem and will not be able to either as long as code is executed on your machine they do not control. Outside of possibly some laws and Safe Browsing etc., nothing technically stops me from creating a website right now that impersonates my bank and shows data from it using login information it asks of me.
